# TPL BroadcastBlock<T> to dispatch same message to multiple consumer with different speed

Tags: task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

As far as I understood `BroadcastBlock` accept a value, readable many times, but as soon a new value is available at its input the value will be overwritten by the new one.
Now I'm a little bit confused, let say I have a producer that feed the `BroadcastBlock`, and that `BroadcastBlock` is linked to many buffer block, each `BufferBlock` is consumed at different speed. Am I sure each consume receive all the messages? My goal is to have the same message dispatched to many consumer, each consumer can lag differently, does my idea work?

Comment: It depends, if your `BufferBlock`s are unbound you won't drop any messages.

Comment: Bound mean they are capped to a certain number of message? This could be a feature to prevent laggy consumers

Comment: @FelicePollano how do you want to handle bounded clients? `BroadcastBlock` is specialized. If you want to multicast a message *with* backoff you'll have to write your own code and decide what to do with slow consumers. Do you await until the slow consumers can accept messages again? Do you bypass them, which probably is no different than using a BroadcastBlock? Do you put *another* bufferblock in the middle to act as an output buffer?

Comment: In a similar case I used a method that reads messages from an `ISourceBlock` in a loop and uses `await target.SendAsync()` to send it to multiple targets. I needed to call different REST services for the same item. If one of the targets was full, the loop itself would pause, which was OK for this particular case. The tricky part was properly propagating completion or cancellation to all targets.